# How to deal with technical and factual disputes?

Tags: discussion

So, even though normally all pure mathematical issues should be able to be settled objectively with careful, strict mathematical treatment.  This is what proofs are about.

But it's not always the case that they get settled here.  But the argument, the back-and-forth, the debate ***does*** serve some educational value for those observing.

How can we have such a debate in this (or any) SE?

The problem I have with just moving it to chat is that the chat does not support $\LaTeX$ or MathJax or whatever.  And the argument ***is*** over mathematics, so we should be able to express the equations and mathematical claims that we are arguing about.

What's wrong with publicly displaying our dirty laundry in the comments (where MathJax **does** work) and everyone can see the content of the dispute and judge for themselves?

Answer (score 2):

> What's wrong with publicly displaying our dirty laundry in the
> comments (where MathJax does work) and everyone can see the content of
> the dispute and judge for themselves?

[In the particular argument that prompted this question](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146240/discussion-on-answer-by-robert-bristow-johnson-the-difference-between-dft-and-df):

- Because it **doesn't answer the question asked**.
- Nor does it **contribute anything to the answer under which it takes place.**

That exchange degenerated into two people holding opposing views talking past each other. And from my perspective neither came out as more convincing that the other.

My suggestion is to bring such arguments here and tag them with `[discussion]`. It even has $\LaTeX$.

Comment: So he's claiming that $x[n]$ must be $0$ outside of $\{0,1,⋯,N−1\}$ and cannot be $5$ nor $5000$ nor the man on the moon nor $$ \frac{1}{N}\sum\limits^{N-1}_{k=0} X[k] \ e^{j2\pi n k/N} $$  (The last is what I'm saying it is.)  Now, if he's going to claim that it must be one and not the other, he has to show why. He has to show how it makes a difference.